# Is it possible to deserialise a Javers Diff?

Tags: java, javers

I am trying to implement a simple diff system for an existing legacy system. I am calculating diffs between multiple *potential* object states using Javers, and persisting them in a serialised version. I do not want to commit the change on my object, just keep track of my diffs.

Is there any way I can recreate the Diff-object given the previously serialised Diff?

Here is my use case:

I have a base Entity that I do *not* want to change. The system receives new versions of the same entity, and I want to know how they differ from my base entity. I find the difference using Javers Diff and can display them, and obviously persist them by serialising the diff, but not restore them from the DB via the serialised diff.

I guess one way to achieve the same would be to persist the entire changed alternative entities, and then calculate the Diff at run-time, but it seems unnecessary to persist whole new Entities when there are only a few fields that have changed. Persisting the alternative versions of my Entity will also mess with my existing system due to unique keys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the correct way to do this. I had been using Jackson ObjectMapper for serialization/deserialization which was giving me problems.

To properly serialize and deserialize I had to use Javers' internal JsonConverter:

```
Diff diff = javers.compare(myObject1, myObject2)

//Tears and pain :(
String omDiff = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(diff)
Diff fromOm = objectMapper.readValue(omDiff, Diff.class)

//yay :)
String jcDiff = jsonConverter.toJson(diff)
Diff fromJc = jsonConverter.fromJson(jcDiff, Diff.class)
```

Comment: Hello @Solvemon, thank you for sharing your success. Please, how did you get an instance of `JsonConverter`? I'm trying to retrieve one from `JsonConverterBuilder` but it fails on runtime: `Unable to invoke no-args constructor for class org.javers.core.diff.Change. Register an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.`

Comment: **FIXED** - OK, for everyone that would do the same thing as me (that is calling `new JsonConverterBuilder().build()`). Don't do it. :) Just call `JAVERS.getJsonConverter()`. That way the persistence will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, we are working on the feature called *shadows*. 
https://github.com/javers/javers/issues/133. So you would be able to restore your orginal domain objects from snapshots persisted in JaversRepository. But restoring original objects from diffs is not possible since diffs captures only a change between two states.